# How to live broadcast multiple audio input to wowza?

Tags: ios, audio, rtmp, live-streaming, wowza

I am using [MediaLibDemos library](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x) for RTMP Streaming Microphone input(voice) to wowza media server.

Is there any way I can stream another audio(like background music) to wowza simultaneously with this microphone input? Can someone tell me how to accomplish this task using this library?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually checked the source code or tested this module, but see if this code can point you in the right direction:

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?590